# PHP Range (Numbers and Alphabets)

Tags: php

```
<?php
$number = range(0,5);
print_r ($number);
?>
```

Above code work , but what if the data is 'ABC001' to 'ABC010' ? I tried with

```
$number = range('ABC001','ABC010');
```

it only return 'A' , any idea how do i do it ? or missing out anything ?

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: you should either extract letters to numbers, or remove non-numeric prefix at all

Comment: From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range): _Character sequence values are limited to a length of one. If a length greater than one is entered, only the first character is used_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arithmetic operations on character variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php#example-122) don't work with the [range()](https://php.net/range) function:

> Character sequence values are limited to a length of one. If a length greater than one is entered, only the first character is used.

You need to roll your own code, e.g.:

```
$from = 'ABC001';
$to = 'ABC010';
$range = [];
for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
    $range[] = $i;
}
var_dump($range);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using [`hexdec()`](https://php.net/hexdec),  [`dechex()`](https://php.net/dechex) and [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map).

```
 $range = array_map('dechex', range(hexdec('ABC001'), hexdec('ABC010')));
```

Comment: This casts everything to lowercase.

Comment: This should work when strings represent short hexadecimal numbers, though in that case you could just handle them internally as numbers (`$from = 0xABC001;`) and convert to string on display. Nice idea anyway.

Comment: @RoAchterberg Exact. You can convert with a simple `strtoupper()`.

Comment: It's clever, but it'll break instantly when you want to do ZYX001 -> ZYX010 for instance. From OP's question I get the sense that the `ABC` was just a random example, and may very well become something else in production.